# BlackBerry:Built-in Date Picker API?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, datetimepicker

In my application screen, i am having a field, where user can to choose his DateOfBirth. 
I want to popup any built-in "Date" calendar or some built-in Date picker to user, so that it will look professional. As i'm new to this development, i wanted to know there is any code sample available to popoup the built-in Date Picker? 
Note: I also want to store the selectable Date by user after selecting it in my existing persistent storage.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a native date picker, you can use the DateField, such as:

```
DateField dateField = new DateField("Date of Birth: ",DateField.DATE);
```

If you want this to 'pop up' you will have to add this to a dialog, unless there is a native component to do this. You can then query this field for its date, it returns a date object:

```
Date date = dateField.getDate();
```

See [Date Field](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/javax/microedition/lcdui/DateField.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when i add this code in my screen VerticalFieldManager, it throws compilation error as 'cannot find symbol constructor DateField(java.lang.String,int) and 'cannot find symbol class Date' even though i have added 'import net.rim.device.api.i18n.DateFormat;' and 'import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.DateField;'. What would the wrong here?

Comment: Ok. I resolved it by adding long value in the second parameter.
 DateField dateField = new DateField("Date of Birth: ",System.currentTimeMillis(),DateField.DATE);

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `DateTimePicker`.  That way you don't have to go through the hassle of creating a `DateField` and adding it to a `Dialog`.

```
DateTimePicker datePicker = DateTimePicker.getInstance();
datePicker.doModal();
Calendar cal = datePicker.getDateTime();
```